# Visual Code launch.json args cannot handle space in datetime

Tags: powershell, args

While debugging powershell in Visual Code I am setting my launch.json file.

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "PowerShell",
        "type": "PowerShell",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "args": ["param1", "param2", "param3", "10/05/2016 13:25:00"],
        "cwd": "${file}"
    }
]
}
```

I get this error: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 
'13:25:00'.

The powershell looks like this:

```
Param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=1)]
[string[]]$Param1,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=2)]
[string[]]$Param2,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=3)]
[string[]]$Param3,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=4)]
[datetime]$MyDateTime)
```

Any ideas on how I can escape this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `"args": "param1 param2 param3 '10/05/2016 13:25:00'"`.  IIRC we went back and forth on taking the args as an array or a single string.  Seemed like a single string worked better.